# What kind of user interface should I use?

Tags: uitableview, ios5, user-interface

Ok, so I have a normal `viewController` that has a `UIScrollView` in it that gives details about distilleries. What I wanted to do was have a list of spirits that are distilled at the distillery that they are reading about. So I attempted to implement a `UITableView` inside of my `UIScrollView`, and after hooking everything up and writing all the delegate and datasource methods I come to find out that a `UITableView` will not work inside of a `UIScrollView`. So does anybody have any ideas as to what kind of User Interface Object I can use to accomplish something like a UITableView's dynamic characteristics? I don't want to use a `UITextView` because it just looks cheap and unstructured. I need something that can dynamically change the number of items shown because not all distilleries will have the same amount of spirits distilled there.

Comment: If you need to add multiple scroll views (incl. table, web and text views), then your design is flawed. Rethink.

Comment: That's why I asked the question. I am in the rethinking stage now.

Comment: When you say you have a scroll view that gives details about distilleries, what do you mean?  A scroll view with a text view in it? I also don't know what you mean by a UITableView doesn't work inside a scroll view -- they come inside a scroll view.

Comment: You might want to try the [UX.SE] site, as this isn't really a programming problem.

Comment: its a scrollview with multiple UILabels for information like the year it was established the name of the distillery etc. The UITableView doesn't show up inside of the scrollview. However it does work when its not inside of the scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing a `UITableView`, there is no need to create a **UIScrollView**.
As a UITableView will automatically increase its size and behave like a scrollable view whenever the content size is larger than the screen.